# How can I make it shorter and better?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I make it shorter and better?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class letter {
     public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 and so forth;
        System.out.print("Enter the number: \t");
        1 = input.nextInt();
        2 = input.nextInt();
        3 = input.nextInt();
        ...and so forth.

        if (1 == A){System.out.println("Your name is anything");}
```

Comment: ___`Java != JavaScript`___

Comment: how can you explain it ? sorry im jsut a newbie

Comment: Use an array and a loop. And google is your friend.

Comment: what is this program supposed to do?

Comment: it should like this as output :

Enter number : 1
Your name is Anything

Comment: This doesn’t seem like a syntactically correct program.

Comment: String 1 , 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6;
  System.out.print("Enter the desired letter: \t");
  1 = input.nextInt();
  2 = input.nextInt();
  3 = input.nextInt();
  4 = input.nextInt();
  5 = input.nextInt();
     {
   if (1 == A){System.out.println("Your name is  cat");}
   else if (2 == B){System.out.println("Your name is  cat");}
   else if (3 == C){System.out.println("Your name is  cat");}
   else if (4 == D){System.out.println("Your name is  cat");}
   else if (5 == E){System.out.println("Your name is  cat");}
   else if (6 == F){System.out.println("Your name is  cat");}
   
  }

Comment: You had a lot of unneeded newlines. I fixed it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for-loop and an array to make it much simpler.  First declare the array `int[] name = new int['how many items you want to enter'];`  Then use a for loop that says

```
for(int i = 0; i<name.length; i++){
name[i]=input.nextInt();
}
```

To access items in the array you put the array name and then the index of the item you want.  In java arrays start at index `0`, so the first element is at an index of `0` ie `name[2]` would give you what ever is at index `2` of `name`.

Comment: Sir , how can i pm you i just want to ask more

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Step 1:  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //More suitable to read data than Scanner Class
    String input = reader.readLine(); //Use appropriate "reading" method for eg. readLine() for reading String

 Step 2 : Iterate according to your need and read data


  Step 3 :   reader.close(); //Close the BufferReader
  }
}
```

Comment: sir how can i pm you ? any gmail acc i jsut want to ask more